# TFF: Custom input spec with custom data set - TypeError: object of type 'TensorSpec" has no len()

Tags: tensorflow-federated

1: problem:
I have the need to use a custom data set in a tff simulation. I have built on the tff/python/research/compression example "run_experiment.py". 
The error:

```
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-47998fd56829>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('B:/projects/openProjects/githubprojects/BotnetTrafficAnalysisFederaedLearning/anomaly-detection/train_v04.py', args=['--experiment_name=temp', '--client_batch_size=20', '--client_optimizer=sgd', '--client_learning_rate=0.2', '--server_optimizer=sgd', '--server_learning_rate=1.0', '--total_rounds=200', '--rounds_per_eval=1', '--rounds_per_checkpoint=50', '--rounds_per_profile=0', '--root_output_dir=B:/projects/openProjects/githubprojects/BotnetTrafficAnalysisFederaedLearning/anomaly-detection/logs/fed_out/'], wdir='B:/projects/openProjects/githubprojects/BotnetTrafficAnalysisFederaedLearning/anomaly-detection')
  File "B:\tools and software\PyCharm 2020.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "B:\tools and software\PyCharm 2020.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "B:/projects/openProjects/githubprojects/BotnetTrafficAnalysisFederaedLearning/anomaly-detection/train_v04.py", line 292, in <module>
    app.run(main)
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "B:/projects/openProjects/githubprojects/BotnetTrafficAnalysisFederaedLearning/anomaly-detection/train_v04.py", line 285, in main
    train_main()
  File "B:/projects/openProjects/githubprojects/BotnetTrafficAnalysisFederaedLearning/anomaly-detection/train_v04.py", line 244, in train_main
    input_spec=input_spec),
  File "B:/projects/openProjects/githubprojects/BotnetTrafficAnalysisFederaedLearning/anomaly-detection/train_v04.py", line 193, in model_builder
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()]
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_federated\python\learning\keras_utils.py", line 125, in from_keras_model
    if len(input_spec) != 2:
TypeError: object of type 'TensorSpec' has no len()
```

highlighting: **TypeError: object of type 'TensorSpec' has no len()**

2: have tried:
I have looked at the response to: [TensorFlow Federated: How can I write an Input Spec for a model with more than one input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61034455/tensorflow-federated-how-can-i-write-an-input-spec-for-a-model-with-more-than-o) 
describing what would be needed to produce a custom input spec for. 
I might be miss understanding input spec.

If I don't need to do this, and there is a better way, please tell.

3: source:

```
    df = get_train_data(sysarg)
    x_train, x_opt, x_test = np.split(df.sample(frac=1,
                                                random_state=17),
                                      [int(1 / 3 * len(df)), int(2 / 3 * len(df))])

    x_train, x_opt, x_test = create_scalar(x_opt, x_test, x_train)
    input_spec = tf.nest.map_structure(tf.TensorSpec.from_tensor, tf.convert_to_tensor(x_train))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TFF's models declare a slightly different input specification than you may be expecting; they generally are expecting *both* the `x` and the `y` values as parameters (IE, data and labels). It is unfortunate that you're hitting that `AttributeError`, as the `ValueError` TFF [would be raising](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/v0.14.0/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/keras_utils.py#L126) is probably more helpful in this case. Inlining the operative parts of the message here:

```
The top-level structure in `input_spec` must contain exactly two elements,
as it must specify type information for both inputs to and predictions from the model.
```

The TLDR in your particular example is: if you have access to the labels as well (`y_train` below), simply change your `input_spec` definition to:

```py
input_spec = tf.nest.map_structure(
    tf.TensorSpec.from_tensor,
    [tf.convert_to_tensor(x_train), tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train)])
```

Comment: OK, looks like this got me to the next error (new post for that). My labels are just my folder names, made a list for those, might still be doing something wrong there.
The model is an autoEncoder, and the data sets are all the large cvs files.